# How to insert long long attribute in sqlite?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sqlite

So it seems there are multiple "how to insert long attribute into sqlite?" questions, but none are a "long long".

I've an attribute which I've set as an INTEGER, and from the looks of it, it takes up to 8 bytes, which is great for using long!

What about a long long? My data is all messed up after trying to insert a long long into an INTEGER (just trying even though I know it shouldn't work :v).

Should I use REAL instead of INTEGER? Or is there something else for "long long"s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `sqlite3_column_int64()` will work.

Comment: In my case I used `sqlite3_bind_int64`, binding is cuter when it comes to inserting special characters.